# Open CV screen recording writing to file at wrong speed

Tags: python, opencv, video, computer-vision

I have some code that captures the screen and then writes that image to an mp4 as a frame. However, when I play the video again, the speed of the video is off. I recorded myself running a timer script and the seconds went down at almost double speed. What do I do? The code I followed off of is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-screen-recorder-using-python/) and it has the same issue when viewing the video.

Here is some of my modified code:

```
def thread_start_recording(out, fps):
    while True:
        img = pyautogui.screenshot()
        frame = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        out.write(np.array(frame))
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            break
        time.sleep(1/20)
     out.release()
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
file_name = "recording.mp4"
fps = 20
out = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name, codec, fps, screensize)
thread = Thread(target=thread_start_recording, args=(out, fps))
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

Comment: There's an `fps` parameter for the video writer, maybe change it? Have you examined what rate you're capturing frames at? Does it match the specified `fps` for the writer? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I specified an fps at 20 in the writer. I think it might be because when I run it from the while loop, the loop runs at an unspecified speed so it will be off. I tried to import time and sleep by 1/fps but that still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: the `1/fps` is good, but that's your total frame time, you spend some of it capturing and writing the frame, so you'd need to only sleep the remaining part of that time before starting your next frame

Comment: include your framing timing code in the question too, that'd help. Or at least an abbreviated version

Comment: I added the code I used for video capture. Is there some code I can add to get rid of the frame error?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but, I think this approach should get better results because the sleep will be only the remaining time.

```
import time
def thread_start_recording(out, fps):
    frame_time = 1/fps 
    while True:
        start = time.time() # Start processing
        img = pyautogui.screenshot()
        frame = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        out.write(np.array(frame))
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            break

        end = time.time() # End of processing
        # Calculate time until next frame
        work_time = end - start
        sleep_time = frame_time - work_time
        if sleep_time < 0:
            raise Exception("Negative sleep time %s means fps should be reduced" % sleep_time)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
     out.release()
```

Comment: When I set fps to 15 it says it is too much. It works only at really low numbers like 3. Shouldn't a screen recorder be able to work at 15

Comment: is it possible for a screen recorder to work at 15fps? yes. That doesn't mean that yours is going to work at 15fps. A "real" screen is going to probably put a lot of work into being efficient and fast, this has none of those optimizations. "How do i make my screen recorder run faster?" is probably material for another question.